# solving the comparison of unicode input string in the file with unicode data

Tags: python, unicode

```
string1=" म नेपाली  हुँ"
string1=string1.split()
string1[0]
'\xe0\xa4\xae'

with codecs.open('nepaliwords.txt','r','utf-8') as f:
     for line in f:
             if string1[0] in line:
                     print "matched string found in file"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 3, in 
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

In the text files, I have large number of Nepali unicode.

Am I doing something wrong here comparing the two unicode string?

How can I print the matched unicode string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `string1` is a *byte string*, encoded to UTF-8. It is *not* a Unicode string. But you used `codecs.open()` to have Python *decode* the file contents to `unicode`. Trying to then use your byte string with a containment test causes Python to implicitly decode the byte string to `unicode` to match types. This fails as the implicit decoding uses ASCII.

Decode `string1` to `unicode` first:

```
string1 = " म नेपाली  हुँ"
string1 = string1.decode('utf8').split()[0]
```

or use a *Unicode* string literal instead:

```
string1 = u" म नेपाली  हुँ"
string1 = string1.split()[0]
```

Note the `u` at the start.

Comment: thanks the string1=u" म नेपाली  हुँ" solved my case.  for string1 = string1.split()[0] the [0] created problem.. thanks

Comment: could you help me in printing the matched string too.